# What's the preferred Java editor for OS X

Tags: java, debugging, macos, intellisense

I currently use Textmate for most of my editing, but am taking a Java course and am wondering if there's a better editor out there, especially one that might have some form of intellisense or active debugging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most, if not all of the usual suspects when it comes to Java IDEs work on OS X. I've personally used Eclipse and NetBeans on OS X - in fact I still have NetBeans installed as it's also a good environment for writing Ruby code.

Of course if you're just looking for an editor and not an IDE, you might want to try out Aquamacs...

Answer (score 3):

If you want code completion, you are not looking for an editor but an IDE.

Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ IDEA all work well on OS X.  JDeveloper I have not tried but the generic version runs under OS X.

Choose the one your instructor recommends (because then he can help you getting started).

Comment: Unfortunately the instructor does all his work in a Windows environment, so he's not much help.

Comment: Ask him anyway.  There is a good chance that the environment he uses is available for OS X.  This is Java, you know.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse works okay.  It has awesome features, but is somewhat buggy / crashy.  It has very good "look and feel" for a Java app on OSX.  Feature parity (as best as I can tell) with Windows/Linux.

Comment: Eclipse 3.5 is very solid for me under OS X.  What bugs/crashes have you seen?

Comment: The maven plugin seems to have some issues, but I don't know if that is OS X specific.

Comment: I can definitely +1 on the maven plugin, but that's probably not OSX specific.

More just sometimes the internal Eclipse state seems to get confused.  Usually restarting or rebuilding the workspace fixes...

Comment: Sounds like it is time to do some bug reporting on the maven plugin, then.  We don't do maven, so that is probably the reason for the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I use Eclipse *quite* heavily on OS X. Lots of plugins, artifact downloading/caching, building, etc. Just make sure you've got the latest Java installed on OS X, and maybe verify that your system will launch Eclipse using Java 6, 64-bit, and make sure you're running Eclipse 3.5, and you should be good to go.

I leave mine running for days at a time, but your mileage may vary depending upon plugins.

Comment: another developer here is indeed running Eclipse quite heavily on OS X and can reach a few days without relaunching it.  Of course on my Linux workstation I've got constantly not one but *two* IntelliJ IDEA instance running (because I like it that way) and they can stay up for months ;)

Answer (score 0):

I like NetBeans and Eclipse, but [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/xcode.html) comes with Mac OS X and [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) is a great stand-alone programming editor.

Answer (score 0):

Go for eclipse. Faster than Netbeans and has lots of plugins.